# Unable to fix "setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component"

Tags: reactjs

Can someone tell me what's wrong with this:

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

class ExampleModal extends Component {
    static propTypes = {
        is_shown: PropTypes.bool
    }

    show = () => {
        console.log('The function gets called, but setState fails');
        this.setState({ is_shown: true });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.show}>Press me</button>
        );
    }
}

export default ExampleModal;
```

Tried googling, going through documentation, and changing the syntax, but still no solution. Can be reproduced for example with [this example app](https://github.com/Kitanotori/react-webpack-babel-hotreload-example/blob/master/src/components/index.jsx) by importing the component above and putting it inside the main `<div>`.

Comment: you dont have defined state. `is_shown` is `prop`

Comment: I think that's unrelated. I tried commenting out propTypes, setting state under constructor, and all kinds of tricks, but nothing helped. I wonder if the issue is caused by my application setup somehow..

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Babel needed [transform-class-properties plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) in order to process the syntax correctly. Unfortunately no error message was shown at any point by Webpack or Babel. It seems that the plugin ordering is also crucial: if I put the transform plugin after the hot loader plugin, the problem persists.

In case someone else is fighting the same problem, here is the .babelrc that fixed the problem:

```
{
    "presets": ["stage-2", "react"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "plugins": [
                [
                    "transform-class-properties",
                    "react-hot-loader/babel"
                ]
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Naturally, you also need to install the plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-transform-class-properties
```

EDIT: embarassing, but actually the reason why this "fixed" the problem was because of typo in the array, which resulted react-hot-loader not being loaded. Hence, react-hot-loader is the culprit, but I have yet to figure why...

Comment: Thank you, I have exactly the same problem if I comment 
//  "react-hot-loader/babel" 
Then it works, I'd like to add react-hot-loader back, did you manage?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing `constructor` I believe.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        is_shown: false
    };
}

show() {
    console.log('The function gets called, but setState fails');
    this.setState({ is_shown: true });
}

render() {
    return (
        <button onClick={this.show.bind(this)}>Press me</button>
    );
}
```

To make your class methods format consistent, I've added `.bind` in `{this.show}` which makes `this` point to this class in `show()` method.

Comment: This works, but my goal was to get the above syntax working. Just now I found out the culprit - transform-class-properties plugin missing from Babel configuration.